# Can't create table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-9.5

After executing the following query:

```
create table sel_pesan(
  pesan_id varchar(7) not null default pesan(tanggal_pesan),
  cust_id varchar(5),
  cp_nama varchar(50),
  cp_tlp varchar (20),
  tanggal_pesan date,
  tanggal_acara date,
  nama_acara varchar(40),
  sesi varchar(10),
  tempat varchar(20),
  jumlah_orang integer,
  petugas varchar(50),
  top date,
  jam_saji time without time zone,
  status_pembayaran boolean default false
);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression

How to fix this?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  Is there some way you stop using a column reference as a default value and still have the logic you want?

Comment: What are you trying to do there? What does this `pesan()` function do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a function and a trigger to assign the default value of `pesan_id` with the value of `tanggal_pesan`.

Note: I don't know if `pesan()` is a custom function. The following code asign the `tanggal_pesan` value converted to string.

Also, you have to change the `pesan(tanggal_pesan)` with a valid string default value, eg: a empty string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sel_pesan_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
 BEGIN
     NEW.pesan_id := to_char(NEW.tanggal_pesan, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
     RETURN NEW;
 END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER sel_pesan_insert_tgr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sel_pesan FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sel_pesan_insert();
```

Comment: the `date` prefix  in `date NEW.tanggal_pesan` is invalid